# Count function in sql query issue

Tags: sql

Please, i have this query here:

```
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM forma";
$result_pag_num = odbc_exec($connection, $query_pag_num) or die(odbc_error());
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['id'];
```

The issue is i get this error here:

```
Undefined index: id where it's:  `$count = $row['id'];`
```

Help please! It won't work without this piece of code here.
I'm using odbc_connect..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: you do not have any field in your SELECT called 'id'. Try: $count = $row['count'];

Comment: Yes, you should be getting a COUNT rather than any single row or rows. How can you have an ID if you don't have any specific row?

Comment: What should i do? I mean, how should i try?

Answer (score 0):

your select function will only return 1 column: "count". you are trying to get to column "id"
here is your fixed code

```
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM forma";
$result_pag_num = odbc_exec($connection, $query_pag_num) or die(odbc_error());
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have any field in your SELECT called 'id'. Try: `$count = $row['count'];`